# Tmux ssh to current server

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, tmux

I use tmux to keep multiple connections to different servers separate and organized. I find I often split windows if I need to keep an eye on more than one thing, but I always close the split, because I prefer the look of a single window. 
Does anyone know of a way to split a window and ssh to the current host with a shortcut? 
For example, tmux is running on my MacBook, and I'm sshed to a centos box. With one shortcut, can I split my centos window into two centos splits? Can I do the same if I'm sshed into another, say ubuntu, box? Does tmux store info about what machine the current window is logged into? (probably not) How could I get that info into my tmux shortcut?

Comment: Why aren't you running tmux on the remote servers instead?  What's the point of persistent sessions on a local laptop, as they will not be persistent.  I connect to my personal server running tmux and have different windows and panes connected to other servers.  Some of those servers that I do a lot of work on also run tmux, which I can nest from the tmux running on my personal server.  You need a different command key combo for nested sessions of course.

Comment: Thanks @paradroid, I forgot about nesting. I could have tmux running on all machines and nest tmux from my laptop. I'd like to avoid this though, because I probably shouldn't be installing tmux on all the machines I'll be connecting to.